# .htaccess in PHP 5.6 and Plesk

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, server, plesk

I am trying to prevent direct access to sub-directories and specific files. My files looks like this:

*.htaccess* in httpdocs:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteRule ^(config\.php) - [F,L,NC]
```

*vhost.conf* in vhosts/domain.test/conf:

```
<Directory "D:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.test\httpdocs">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

With XAMPP on my local machine (standard settings) everything works fine. Access to *config.php* gets denied. The server just ignores the .htaccess file. I'm working with Plesk 17.8.11 (Onyx) on Windows Server 2016 VM.

I restarted IIS, but it is still possible to open *config.php* via URL (even if it results in an empty screen). I also tried to add:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to my '*Additional directives*' in Plesk PHP-Settings, but it didn't do it either.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to .htaccess in Windows would be the web.config file and therefore it is possible to use .htaccess rules on Windows server with IIS but it has to be done through the aforementioned file.

The web.config file has a different syntax than .htaccess file so a translation is needed.

The following links will help to understand and translate the .htaccess file to a web.config one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig